# Determinism in a fully observable environment

Tags: stochastic-processes

A train of thoughts that I would love to have different sets of eyes on:

In a partially observable environment, one would say a process is stochastic if repeating the same set of actions lead to different results. For example, throwing a paper airplane in the air multiple times, each throw would lead the plane to a different path through the air.

Now given the previous assertion, wouldn't a fully observable environment always be deterministic? In other words, having all the dimensions in the environment available and measured, one would be able through infinitely many evaluations to determine how each dimension affects the process. In the example of the airplane, given data of all possible dimensions in its environment, one would be able to determine its exact path with a 100% certainty.

Another example, playing a two players board game is in practice stochastic for player A given that what player B does cannot be known with a probability of 100%. However, hypothetically speaking, if player B was fully observable, then player A would know exactly how player B would behave and therefore the fully observable environment becomes deterministic.

Comment: Balancing a needle on its tip is a non-deterministic experiment in *classical* mechanics.  Indeed, any physical system that is at an unstable equilibrium is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, but you have to go to quantum mechanics for the answer. There are several reasons why quantum mechanics destroys determinism.

1. You cannot, even in principle, know all the positions and momenta of all particles with arbitrary precision at any moment in time, due to the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. His statement of the principle is more statistical than it is concerned with a particular moment in time, but it still applies.
2. Measuring a system changes the system. This seems very weird at the macroscopic level, but at the microscopic level, it totally makes sense. Here's how it works. To observe anything at the microscopic level, you have to bounce things off it and see the resulting pattern. It's the only known way to observe. So, imagine observing a bowling ball by bouncing ping-pong balls off it. This would correspond to the macroscopic picture; it probably wouldn't change the bowling ball's position or momentum very much. But now go to the microscopic picture: now you're really talking about bouncing ping-pong balls off of other ping-pong balls. The moment you do that, you're going to be less certain about where it is.
3. Finally, to be completely observed, a system would have to have $6$ variables for every particle ($3$ position, $3$ momentum variables), and you would likely have on the order of Avagadro's number of particles. It's not possible to measure that many variables on that scale, just from a technology standpoint. Even if you could measure them all, setting up all the differential equations of motion would be impossible on any computing device known to man, and you'd get round-off error, etc.

For these reasons, some theoretical, and some practical, full determinism is impossible to achieve.

Comment: What if we totally omit the observer and rather talk about determinism as a property of the environment? As if we are describing a system that we are not interested in observing bur rather describing it as it is.

Comment: Then it depends on whether you accept the so-called Copenhagen interpretation (majority viewpoint among physicists) or not. The Copenhagen interpretation says that, until you measure a particle, it actually doesn't even HAVE a defined position or momentum. Not all physicists accept that, though.

Comment: Thank you, very insightful.

Comment: You're very welcome!